# c# printing a windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing, windows-forms-designer

I found this code to print

```
// The PrintDialog will print the document
// by handling the document's PrintPage event.
private void document_PrintPage(object sender, 
System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{

    // Insert code to render the page here.
    // This code will be called when the control is drawn.

    // The following code will render a simple
    // message on the printed document.
    string text = "In document_PrintPage method.";
    System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font
        ("Arial", 35, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

    // Draw the content.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, printFont, 
        System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
}


// Declare the PrintDocument object.
private System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument docToPrint =
    new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    PrintDialog PrintDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
    // Allow the user to choose the page range he or she would
    // like to print.
    PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;

    // Show the help button.
    PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = true;

    // Set the Document property to the PrintDocument for 
    // which the PrintPage Event has been handled. To display the
    // dialog, either this property or the PrinterSettings property 
    // must be set 
    PrintDialog1.Document = docToPrint;

    DialogResult result = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();

    // If the result is OK then print the document.
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        docToPrint.Print();
    }
}
```

I execute it and the result of the printing is an `empty page`, my question is where can i put the data to print? and how can i make the printed data as rows each row has label and value.

Comment: You should have seen "In document_PrintPage method". Find out what went wrong first.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I saw an empty page

Comment: I don't see any code linking up the PrintPage event. It probably never fires.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I thought it is a function that is being fired when the printing starts or something, what do you suggest please? adding the code insdie it to the code insdie the button event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create the PrintDocument as a private member:

```
// Declare the PrintDocument object.
private System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument docToPrint =
    new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
```

But that makes it hard to attach the event handler at the right moment. I suggest using the constructor:

```
// Declare the PrintDocument object.
private System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument docToPrint; 
     //= new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

public Form1()   // the Form ctor
{
   InitializeComponents();
   docToPrint = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
   docToPrint.PrintPage += document_PrintPage; // the missing piece
}
```

Comment: please final question , I tried to add this ` e.Graphics.DrawString("asdfasdf", valueFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, 10, 10);` at the end, but I keep having just the `In document_PrintPage method.`, while the new text, which is `asdfasd` is not added to the printing page. help please

Comment: i just notice that I got the value, but it becomes above the previous one :( :( help please

Comment: kindly check my qeustion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218779/c-sharp-how-to-print-information-in-table