# c# how to print information in table?

Tags: c#, .net, printing

I am using this code to print

```
System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font
        ("Arial", 35, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

    System.Drawing.Font valueFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 20, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);

    // Draw the content.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(text, printFont, 
        System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("asdfasdf", valueFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, 20, 20);
```

as you see, I am setting the location of the printing values like this:

`10,10`

and

`20,20`

and this is the result:

[image]

my question is: is there a way to make c# set the location automatically?

I would prefer If there is a way to print the data as table because i have 52 textbox and I would like the printing page to be like this:

```
------------------------
label1:    textbox1.Text
------------------------
label2:    textbox2.Text
------------------------
```

Comment: Write your data to RichTextBox, WebBrowserControl etc, and use their printing capabilities.

Comment: @L.B I already finished my project and I still just need to do the printnig. Thus, I can't change the application now. I already have 52 check boxes with validation and network streaming. I can't change them to anyother controller. is there anyway to solve my problem please?

Comment: It doesn't require to change the whole project. Instead of doing `DrawString`s, you'll write your data to a control and print it.

Comment: @L.B could you give me a just **one example** that has a label and a textbox please? I appreicate your help

Comment: `string s = label1.Text + ":" + textBox1.Text + Environment.NewLine;  richTextBox1.Text = s;` Now print the content of *richTextBox1*. *OR* form an html string put it to webbrowsercontrol and then print it.

Comment: @L.B can I imply from your comment that I can print my form **exactly** as it is ? when you said `OR form as html string put it to webbrowsercontrolelr` ?

Comment: What you see in browser will be what you print, if this is what you are asking.

Comment: @L.B I am not developing a web app my friend, I am developing a windows form application and now I need to print the data. i though you said that I can print the data to be exactly like it is in the form (i mean like i design it) got me please? and in your example you didn't create the `rickTextBox1` rigtht?

Comment: I didn't say It should be a web app. OK, I hope one day you'll understand what I mean, till then, good luck...

Comment: _is there a way to make c# set the location automatically?_ - No, this is pixel-level drawing. Just develop a for-loop and estimate the y-scale. For accuracy you can use [MeasureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @L.B: When you have a few text-fragments in GDI+, a RTB is not the best or easiest way to get a nice output.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I can also post an answer based on html+webbrowser control but first OP must ne ready to it...

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec No, I am waiting to see how you will solve it with pure GDI+ methods and then you to think if there would be simpler solutions

Comment: @L.B check my solution please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220290/why-are-there-extra-spaces-in-this-context