# Why are there extra spaces in this context?

Tags: c#, .net, printing, arabic

This is my code to print some data:

```
System.Drawing.Font valueFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
string dataToPrint = "";
dataToPrint += fixLength("رقم بطاقة التسويق") + farmID.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("إسم صاحب المزرعة") + farmOwner.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("رقم المزرعة") + farmNumber.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("الموبايل") + farmMobile.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("الإمارة") + emaraNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("المنطقة") + areaNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("الإقليم") + regionNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("مركز الإستلام") + receivingCenterName.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("خلاص") + khalas.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("فرض") + fardh.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("لولو") + otherLulu.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("خنيزي") + khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("بومعان") + boumaan.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("برحي") + barhi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("جش خزمة") + jeshKharma.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("رزيز") + reziz.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("جبري") + jabri.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("عنبرة المدينة") + anbaretAlMadina.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("شيشي") + shishi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("دباس") + dabbas.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("نبتة سيف") + nabtetSaif.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("خضراوي") + khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("هلالي") + hilali.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("مكتومي") + maktoumy.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("نميشي") + namishi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("سلطانة") + sultanah.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("بقلة الطوعة") + baqlatAlTawaa.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("بقلة الدحالة") + baqlatAlDahla.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("بقلة الرارنجا") + baqlatAlRarenja.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("سكري") + sukary.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("صقعي") + saqei.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("بوزيد") + abuZebed.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("مجدول") + majdoul.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("شبيبي") + shabibi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("يواني") + youwani.Text + Environment.NewLine;
dataToPrint += fixLength("يردي") + yardi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft);
e.Graphics.DrawString(dataToPrint, valueFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 600, 20, format);
```

This is the fixLength function:

```
public string fixLength(string value) {
        int difference = 40 - value.Length;
        if(difference>0)
            for (int i = 0; i < difference; i++)
            {
                value = value + " ";
            }
        return value;
    }
```

This is the result:
 [image]

please notice that even though I used the fix lenth but the printed data still not having the same alignment.

Comment: Is that a fixed-width font? I would be surprised if a script font was fixed width.

Comment: size of character != size of space. or you should use monospaced font

Comment: When you want columns, compute the X for DrawString(). Spaces won't do it, Tabs are difficult.

Comment: @bansi yes maybe the size of char != size of space but I want to use the `Arial` font. could you hellp me to fix my fixLength function?

Comment: @HenkHolterman could you help me to fix the `fixLength` function please?

Comment: @JohnSaunders the font is `Arial` and the size is `15`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, that fixLength() method is the wrong approach.

Comment: @HenkHolterman so what is the good approach ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman maybe the good approach is to caluculate the pixels of the word and then add a specific pixles to it?

Comment: Compute X and Y and draw the individual strings. Or find out how to set TabStops on a Graphics object.

Comment: you will need to use [Graphics.MeasureString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring(v=vs.110).aspx) or position your second column using graphic. adding space won't work

Comment: What kind of application is this? Windows Forms? If so, then refer to the [TextRenderer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution my self which is

```
        System.Drawing.Font valueFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
        string dataToPrint = "";
        string valuesToPrint = "";

    dataToPrint += "رقم بطاقة التسويق" +  Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += farmID.Text + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("إسم صاحب المزرعة") +  Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += farmOwner.Text + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("رقم المزرعة") + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += farmNumber.Text + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("الموبايل") + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += farmMobile.Text + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("الإمارة") + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += emaraNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("المنطقة") + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += areaNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("الإقليم")  + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += regionNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("مركز الإستلام") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += receivingCenterName.Text + Environment.NewLine;

   dataToPrint += ("خلاص") + khalas.Text + Environment.NewLine;
   valuesToPrint += khalas.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("فرض") + fardh.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += fardh.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("لولو") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += otherLulu.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("خنيزي") + khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("بومعان") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += boumaan.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("برحي") +Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += barhi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("جش خزمة") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += jeshKharma.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("رزيز") + reziz.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += reziz.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("جبري") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += jabri.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("عنبرة المدينة") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += anbaretAlMadina.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("شيشي") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += shishi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("دباس")  + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += dabbas.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("نبتة سيف") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += nabtetSaif.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("خضراوي") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("هلالي") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += hilali.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("مكتومي") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += maktoumy.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("نميشي") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += namishi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("سلطانة") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += sultanah.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("بقلة الطوعة")  + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += baqlatAlTawaa.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("بقلة الدحالة") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += baqlatAlDahla.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("بقلة الرارنجا") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += baqlatAlRarenja.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("سكري") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += sukary.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("صقعي") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += saqei.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("بوزيد") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += abuZebed.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("مجدول") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += majdoul.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("شبيبي") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += shabibi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("يواني") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += youwani.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("يردي") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += yardi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("خدي") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += khadi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("حاتمي") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += hatimi.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("نغال") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += neghal.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("مجموعة مساير") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += otherSayer.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("إجمالي مثمر") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += totalFructiferous.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("إجمالي غير مثمر") + Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += totalUnFructiferous.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("إجمالي الأفحل") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += totalAfhal.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("الإجمالي العام") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += generalTotal.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("كبير المعرفين") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += seniorSupervisors.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("مساعد") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += assistant.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("مدخل البيانات")+  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += dataEntry.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    dataToPrint += ("صاحب المزرعة أو من ينوب عنه") +  Environment.NewLine;
    valuesToPrint += farmOnwerOrBehalf.Text + Environment.NewLine;

    StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(dataToPrint, valueFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 600, 20, format);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(valuesToPrint, valueFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, 400, 20, format);
```

and this is the result

[image]

Comment: +1 very good use of the comments to find your own solution, and thanks for posting it here for others to benefit from. My only comment is that, when doing so many string concatenations, it begins to be more efficient to use the `StringBuilder` class, and the `Append` method.

Comment: And we don't really have to see all those lines... a sample of 2 or 3 would be enough.

Comment: @JohnSaunders now when I want to make the out put better, I tried to add `----------` below each row but the page fill, please check my new quesiton http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220835/c-sharp-how-to-print-in-another-page

Comment: @HenkHolterman pleae check my new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220835/c-sharp-how-to-print-in-another-page the page becomes full and i don't know how to tell c# to print on another page

Comment: The weakness of this approach is when you encounter a very long word (that wraps and screws up the line-by-line matching). And when your page gets full...

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't have values to long, usually it is just numbers and a name (18 chars) but now I do have the problem that the page is full, I posted a question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220835/c-sharp-how-to-print-in-another-page