# how to print in another page

Tags: c#, .net, printing

This is my code to print a data:

```
private void document_PrintPage(object sender,
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

            System.Drawing.Font valueFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 15, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular);
            string dataToPrint = "";
            string valuesToPrint = "";

        dataToPrint += "رقم بطاقة التسويق" +  Environment.NewLine+"-----------------------------------------------"+Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += farmID.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("إسم صاحب المزرعة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += farmOwner.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

            dataToPrint += ("رقم المزرعة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
            valuesToPrint += farmNumber.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

            dataToPrint += ("الموبايل") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
            valuesToPrint += farmMobile.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

            dataToPrint += ("الإمارة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
            valuesToPrint += emaraNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

            dataToPrint += ("المنطقة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
            valuesToPrint += areaNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

            dataToPrint += ("الإقليم") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
            valuesToPrint += regionNameArabic.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

            dataToPrint += ("مركز الإستلام") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
            valuesToPrint += receivingCenterName.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("خلاص") + khalas.Text + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += khalas.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

       dataToPrint += ("فرض") + fardh.Text + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
       valuesToPrint += fardh.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("لولو") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += otherLulu.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("خنيزي") + khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("بومعان") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += boumaan.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("برحي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += barhi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("جش خزمة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += jeshKharma.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("رزيز") + reziz.Text + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += reziz.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("جبري") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += jabri.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("عنبرة المدينة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += anbaretAlMadina.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("شيشي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += shishi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("دباس") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += dabbas.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("نبتة سيف") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += nabtetSaif.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("خضراوي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += khedrawi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("هلالي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += hilali.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("مكتومي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += maktoumy.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("نميشي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += namishi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("سلطانة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += sultanah.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("بقلة الطوعة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += baqlatAlTawaa.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("بقلة الدحالة") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += baqlatAlDahla.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("بقلة الرارنجا") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += baqlatAlRarenja.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("سكري") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += sukary.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("صقعي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += saqei.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("بوزيد") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += abuZebed.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("مجدول") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += majdoul.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("شبيبي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += shabibi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("يواني") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += youwani.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("يردي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += yardi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("خدي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += khadi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("حاتمي") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += hatimi.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("نغال") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += neghal.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("مجموعة مساير") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += otherSayer.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("إجمالي مثمر") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += totalFructiferous.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("إجمالي غير مثمر") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += totalUnFructiferous.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("إجمالي الأفحل") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += totalAfhal.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("الإجمالي العام") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += generalTotal.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("كبير المعرفين") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += seniorSupervisors.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("مساعد") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += assistant.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("مدخل البيانات") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += dataEntry.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        dataToPrint += ("صاحب المزرعة أو من ينوب عنه") + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;
        valuesToPrint += farmOnwerOrBehalf.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

        StringFormat format = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dataToPrint, valueFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 600, 20, format);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(valuesToPrint, valueFont, System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, 400, 20, format);
    }


    // Declare the PrintDocument object.
        private System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument docToPrint; //=
        //new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();

    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (validate())
        {
            PrintDialog PrintDialog1 = new PrintDialog();
            // Allow the user to choose the page range he or she would
            // like to print.
            PrintDialog1.AllowSomePages = true;

            // Show the help button.
            PrintDialog1.ShowHelp = true;

            // Set the Document property to the PrintDocument for 
            // which the PrintPage Event has been handled. To display the
            // dialog, either this property or the PrinterSettings property 
            // must be set 
            PrintDialog1.Document = docToPrint;

            DialogResult result = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog();

            // If the result is OK then print the document.
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                docToPrint.Print();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a lot of data and the data cant' be fill in one page , but when I fired that code, i got a single page with a lot of information missing, in other words, the data is printed to one page and when that page fills, the code is not writing to another page

Comment: You are relying on multiline version of DrawString but that isn't Page aware...

Comment: @HenkHolterman I found that this is e.hasmorepages. but when I made it true, i go into an invinitive loop of priting, I should  have something like this: `stringToPrint = (stringToPrint  - stringHasPrinted)` and then `e.hasMorepage = (stringToPrint.length>0)` but the problem that I don't know how to get the `stringHasPrinted` could you help me in this part?

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for editing. I wrote a comment above, could you check and help me to find the `stringHasPrinted`? or if you have another approach

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that familiar with this sort of graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple answers and articles about the use of `e.HasMorePages` but they will all break your current layout method. That can't be helped.

The recipe:

1. Organize your data before printing. Make a `List<DataClass> Data` where DataClass has Label and Value properties. The list has to be indexable.
2. introduce a `lastLine` item counter as a field on the Form (like docToPrint)
3. set  `lastLine` to 0 in the BeginPrint event
4. change your Printpage event to something like:

   ```
   var box = e.MarginBounds;

   //todo: calculate X, Y and H from box.

   while (lastLine < Data.Count)
   {
       e.Graphics.DrawStrin(Data[lastLine].Label, this.Font, Brushes.Black, X1, Y);
       e.Graphics.DrawStrin(Data[lastLine].Value, this.Font, Brushes.Navy, X2, Y);

       lastLine += 1;
       Y += H;
       if (Y >= box.Bottom)  // page full
           break;
   }
   e.HasMorePages = lastLine < Data.Count;
   ```

There is 1 call to the Printpage event per Page. It's up to you to keep track of the state (line) that's next.

Also, make sure to use the PrintPreviewDialog to save some time and paper.

Comment: that is a big change :( Anyway I will do it and update u

Comment: please before I start, i have a qeustion about ur solution `dataToPrint += ("خلاص") +  Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine;` shold be the lable and this `valuesToPrint += khalas.Text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;` should be the value right?

Comment: and please how to `todo: calculate X, Y and H from box.` appreciate your help but really I am not familiar with priting and I must finish the project today

Comment: Yes I think so. This is left-to-right, you'll have to adapt. When you've got it working you'll find it easy to make repeating headers on each page. Hint: start with just `H=20` instead of MeasureString.

Comment: and please how to `todo: calculate X, Y and H from box.` appreciate your help but really I am not familiar with priting and I must finish the project today

Comment: please i need right to left, I have lost 3 hours to make my current data right to left :(

Comment: X1 = box.Left+10, X2 = box.Left + 210, H = 20, Y = box.Top + 10.

Comment: The `StringFormat` should still work. Maybe with different X values.

Comment: I am trying your solution now. really thanks for your efforts with me will update u as soon as possible

Comment: Sure, good luck. And make sure to use the PrintPreviewDialog to save some time and paper.

Comment: I made these changes to your code ` int X1 = box.Left + 200;int X2 = box.Left + 410;int H = 60;` and made the X2 for labels instead of values and made X1 for values instead of labels and the result is uploaded here http://www.mediafire.com/view/s9jbiw9vat9xf2k/test.PDF but still I couldn't understand your point by saying `PrintPreviewDialog` where to put that please?

Comment: maybe the document is not sounds good on `mediafire` but it is perfect on my machine.

Comment: If it looks good then it's OK. Your 400/600 was indeed my X1/X2. And PrintPreviewDialog is a replacement for PrintDialog (or offer both as options). But PrintPreviewDialog is easier when developing.

Comment: from our little talk today, do you think i am a bad developer?

Comment: my last question for today :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221820/not-all-printed-values-are-encoded-utf-8 may you check please? really last question